# Calling bean method using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, icefaces

I want to show a list of options to the user when he/she clicks on an `inputText` component. I need to call a bean method by JavaScript using `onclick` attribute in IceFaces.

```
<ice:inputText id="inputText1" partialSubmit="true" value="" onclick="" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bean method is any of the methods defined in the backing bean of the JSF file. This backing bean in simple words, a class and the backend of the JSF page.

Comment: Don't you after all just want *autocomplete* input? Then use `ice:selectInputText` instead. Tutorial here: http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/autocomplete-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Neall said, you need to initiate an XMLHttpRequest and return the data to the client. There are many ways to do this and I don't know the framework you are referring to, but in general, you initiate the XMLHttpRequest passing some parameters -if needed- to a web method, for example, and then return the data in JSON format. When you issue the request it usually has a callback function for success and one for error. On the sucess event, you parse the JSON response and do whatever you need to do with it.

Look at here, for example:

http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/

Comment: [IceFaces](http://icefaces.org) is already an ajaxical JSF component library. Bringing own JS in is plain cumbersome. The OP made the mistake to think in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run server-side code when the user takes some action on the client side. You probably want to initiate an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest).

The XMLHttpRequest basically just hits a URL, optionally returning some data to the browser. This is what people usually call AJAX. (For Asynchronous Javascript And XML - although people usually use JSON instead of XML.)

Comment: Hi! Actually I am using icefaces which is already an ajax framework.

Comment: What I wish to do is.. to show a list of options to the user when he/she clicks on an inputtext component (The javascript onclick event).